# What is the most succinct way of making a choice dependent on an attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have some XML where you could have

```
<a type="b">
    <b></b>
</a>
```

or

```
<a type="c">
    <c></c>
</a>
```

or

```
<a type="d">
    <d></d>
</a>
```

but the following is not valid:

```
<a type="c">
    <b></b>
</a>
```

I am trying to create an XML Schema that represents this, but, if I understand it correctly, the following doesn't correctly tie the type attribute to the contents of the tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="a" type="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

    <xs:complexType name="A">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="AType" use="required" />
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="B" />
            <xs:group ref="C" />
            <xs:group ref="D" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="AType">
        <restriction base="xs:string">
            <enumeration value="b"/>
            <enumeration value="c"/>
            <enumeration value="d"/>
        </restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="B">
        STUFF
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="C">
        OTHER STUFF
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="D">
        YET MORE STUFF
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is the only way to do this correctly to be incredibly verbose like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="a" type="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

    <xs:complexType name="A">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="B" />
            <xs:group ref="C" />
            <xs:group ref="D" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="B">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="b" />
        STUFF
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="C">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="c" />
        OTHER STUFF
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="D">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="d" />
        YET MORE STUFF
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You're using XML and complain about verbosity? (zing! SCNR) Okay, seriously: Have you tried just using different parent tags for groups of A/B/C tags? Basing this on an attribute doesn't seem too common (or wise) to me...

Comment: @delnan It isn't my design, I am just writing the schema for it.  In reality, the tag names don't differ, the expected attributes do.

Comment: XSD wasn't really designed on the basis of being able to describe arbitrary XML document designs: it comes with its own assumptions about how documents *should* be designed.

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way to do this in XSD 1.0. It can be done easily in XSD 1.1 using the new feature of "conditional type assignment". This feature is supported in the latest releases of the schema processors that come with Saxon and Xerces.